# MediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() always returns 0 while playing internet radio

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I open an online audio `AAC` stream with `MediaPlayer`. The radio server allows to listen to broadcast archive with a special parameter in URL.

```
http://extstreamer800.moskva.fm/stream/7881/1425837912.0?format=aac&hash=c4f64a41d00dafd3c0c7b989d12b3fec
```

(`hash` will expire soon making URL invalid. A new one can be obtained from the online player at http://moskva.fm )

My program has a text field which is supposed to contain the current position. I periodically call `player.getCurrentPosition()` and format milliseconds to string.

I noticed that when MediaPlayer is playing a stream with unknown duration, `getCurrentPosition()` always returns 0. I'm testing this with AVD 4.4.2

```
        try {
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse("http://extstreamer800.moskva.fm/stream/7881/1425837912.0?format=aac&hash=c4f64a41d00dafd3c0c7b989d12b3fec"));
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener(){
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.start();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Log.e("x", "currentPosition = " + mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                        }
                    }, 10000);
                }
            });
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Can you share the initialization of the media player?

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer instead of comment because this would not really fit as a comment. 
According to the question you are using a onPrepared callback, is that right?
If streaming from a external source i would do it like this:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri);
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener(){

@Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
    }
});
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

You don't seem to be using the `mp` variable in this callback.

Another reason might be the emulator. Did you try your solution on a real device?

Comment: Did you also try a real device?